# Suppress chapter number from the equation number but restart automatically in each chapter from 1

Tags: equations, sectioning, chapters, subsection, equation-number

using the following code, I suppressed the chapter number from the equation. but it does not stop and in the next chapter the equation number does not start from 1. What should I do?

I have used the following code:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
```

the problem is that in the next chapter, the equation number does not start from 1 and it continues.

I also want the format mentioned above for the table and figure.

Comment: `\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{chapter}
\makeatother`, but how are you going to reference an equation if there are several equations with the same number?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unless your TeX distribution is several years old *and* you refuse to update your TeX distribution, it shouldn't be necessary to run `\usepackage{chngcntr}`.